# Owl Carousel / ngx-owl-carousel-o touch drag always return to first slide

Tags: angular, carousel, single-page-application, responsive

how you doing? Hope your fine.

I am using ngx-owl-carousel-o (Owl Carousel) in an Angular project, and when I touched/drag from first page to second page, everything is doing fine. But the problem is when I do the same from second page to third page: My carousel automatically goes to first page and goes to second page, as if I started from the first.

Have anyone an idea what is going on? I have tried any configuration possible.

Below is my actual configuration.
Thank you very much!

```
OwlOptions = {
    loop: false,
    margin: 15,
    mouseDrag: true,
    freeDrag: true,
    touchDrag: true,
    autoplay: false,
    dots: false,
    navSpeed: 700,
    nav: true,
    rewind: true,
    mergeFit: true,
    slideBy: 1,
    navText: ['', '<img src="/assets/icons/ic-arrow-right.svg" />'],
    responsive: {
      0: {
        items: 1.5
      },
      400: {
        items: 2
      },
      740: {
        items: 3
      },
      1240: {
        items: 3.5
      }
    }
  };
```

I have tried any configuration possible, and I expected the touch/drag function in mobile results in the right way.

Answer (score 0):

There might be issue with `freeDrag: true` try to make it `false`.